# base class for fragment manager android

Tags: android, android-fragments

here's is a big deal.I have android project which has multiple activities with different packages,
some activities has list view with custom adapter with button and spinner. as same other activities have list view but different widget.
for example. A employee list view with custom adapter where button click in list view will show employee detail(Activity) and student list view on button click will show student detail(Activity).
redirection of activity are made in custom adapter.
some activity has only view on which click another activity are open.

I want to convert them to fragment. I know the interfaces and call back fragment to activity and activity will replace the fragment.

I just only need the logic how can I manage whole swapping of fragment. instead of using number of interfaces and callback.
here's the link [Android managing fragments from activity elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080163/android-managing-fragments-from-activity-elegantly) answered by Alireza that I studied. it can make my fragment swapping centralize but it will need many conditions on each event of list adapter button click in fragment or simple button in fragment to replace fragment.

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncRequest.OnAsyncRequestComplete {
private boolean boolScroll = true;
private int incre = 1;
private ListAdapter adapter;
private EditText txtNoticeSearch;
private ListView listView;
private Button btnSearch;
private Button btnClear;
private View footer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notice_activity);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    findViewByID();
    listView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener());
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            incre = 1;
            boolScroll = true;
            txtNoticeSearch.setText(null);
            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.clear();
            search(true);

        }
    });
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String std = txtNoticeSearch.getText().toString();

            if (std.trim().length() > 1) {
                incre = 1;
                boolScroll = true;
                if (adapter != null)
                    adapter.clear();
                try {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService
                            (INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(new View(List.this).getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                search(false);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter atleast two character.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

        }
    });
    txtNoticeSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            incre = 1;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
    search(true);
}

private AbsListView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener() {
    return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {


        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            int threshold = 5;
            int count = listView.getCount();

            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold) {

                    if (boolScroll) {
                        if (txtNoticeSearch.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
                            search(false);
                        else
                            search(true);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {
        }
    };
}

private void findViewByID() {
    txtNoticeSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNoticeSearch);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewNotice);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    footer = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.listview_loading_footer, listView, false);
}



private void search(boolean bool) {
    if (listView.getFooterViewsCount() == 0)
        listView.addFooterView(footer);
    String URL;
    if (bool) {
        URL = new SqLite(getApplicationContext()).returnDefaultURI() + "notice/0/" + incre;
        incre = incre + 1;
    } else {
        URL = new SqLite(getApplicationContext()).returnDefaultURI() + "notice/" +
                txtNoticeSearch.getText().toString().trim() + "/" + incre;
        incre = incre + 1;
    }

    AsyncRequest asyncRequest;
    if (incre > 2)
        asyncRequest = new AsyncRequest(List.this, "GET", null, null, 1);
    else
        asyncRequest = new AsyncRequest(List.this, "GET", null, "Fetching data", 1);

    asyncRequest.execute(URL);
}

@Override
public void asyncResponse(String response, int apiKey) {
    if (response != null)
        if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("{\"Message\":\"Session Expired !\"}"))
            new AppUtility(List.this).sessionExpiresState(List.this);
        else
            switch (apiKey) {
                case 1:
                    if (listView.getFooterViewsCount() > 0)
                        if (listView.getAdapter() != null)
                            listView.removeFooterView(footer);

                    fillListView(response);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    openFile(response);
                    break;
            }

}

private void fillListView(String response) {
    try {
        ArrayList<ListRowItem> lstItem;
        if (listView.getCount() == 0) {
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListRowItem>>() {
            }.getType();
            lstItem = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
            adapter = new ListAdapter(List.this, lstItem);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListRowItem>>() {
            }.getType();
            lstItem = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                adapter.addAll(lstItem);
            } else {
                for (ListRowItem items : lstItem) {
                    adapter.add(items);
                }
            }
        }
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        if (response.contains("{\"Message\":\"Data not found !\"}")) {
            if (incre == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                boolScroll = false;
            } else
                boolScroll = false;
        }
    }
}

class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListRowItem> {
    private final Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context asyncTask, java.util.List<ListRowItem> items)       {
        super(asyncTask, R.layout.notice_listitem, items);
        this.context = asyncTask;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final ListRowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notice_listitem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSno);
            holder.txtNoticePublishDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id
                    .txtNoticePublishDate);
            holder.btnView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnView);
            holder.txtNoticeDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id
                    .txtNoticeDescription);
            holder.txtNoticeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoticeName);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.txtSno.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        holder.txtNoticeDescription.setText(new AppUtility().TitleCase(rowItem.getDescription
                ()));
        holder.txtNoticeName.setText(new AppUtility().TitleCase(rowItem.getFileTitle()));

        try {
            holder.txtNoticePublishDate.setText(String.valueOf((new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM " +
                    "yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)).format((new SimpleDateFormat
                    ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)).parse(rowItem.getUpdateDate()))));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            holder.txtNoticePublishDate.setText(new AppUtility().TitleCase(rowItem
                    .getUpdateDate()));
        }

        // here i want to replace fragment by calling back to fragment and 
         // then activity to call replace fragment 
        holder.btnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
                downloadFile.setName(rowItem.getFileTitle());
                downloadFile.setExtension(rowItem.getContentType().split("/")[1]);
                downloadFile.setDownloadUrl(new SqLite(context).returnDefaultURI() +
                        "notice/" + rowItem.getDocumentUploadID());
                downloadFile.setFolderName(context.getResources().getString(R.string
                        .folder_name));
                downloadFile.setMessage();
                AsyncRequest asyncRequest = new AsyncRequest(context, downloadFile, 2);
                asyncRequest.execute(downloadFile.getDownloadUrl());
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtSno;
        TextView txtNoticeName;
        TextView txtNoticeDescription;
        TextView txtNoticePublishDate;
        Button btnView;

    }
}

class ListRowItem {
    private final String FileTitle;
    private final String Description;
    private final String ContentType;
    private final int DocumentUploadID;
    private final String UpdateDate;

    ListRowItem() {
        this.FileTitle = "";
        this.Description = "";
        this.ContentType = "";
        this.DocumentUploadID = 0;
        this.UpdateDate = "";
    }

    public String getFileTitle() {
        return FileTitle;
    }

    public int getDocumentUploadID() {

        return DocumentUploadID;
    }

    public String getUpdateDate() {

        return UpdateDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public String getContentType() {

        return ContentType;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code. Whatever you have till now.

Comment: in adapter on button click how can i replace fragment with detail view fragment  if all this is a list view inside fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do it.

Method 1: 
Pass your FragmentManager to the adapter constructor and replace the fragment you want to.

Method 2:
Step 1 : Create an interface

```
public interface FragmentChange {
    void changeFragment(Fragment fragment);

}
```

Step 2 : Create a BaseActivity, other activities will inherits it

Step 3 : implement the FragmentChange in BaseActivity and add functioanality to changeFragment method to change the fragment.

Step 4 : onAttach(Activity activity) cast activity to BaseActivity and pass to the constructor of your Adapter. and call method of that interface on your button click.