# keep only one instance of a fragment, when switching with Navigation Drawer with back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back-stack

I need to manage back button handle in navigation drawer with single instance of fragment.

```
FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = fManager.findFragmentByTag("uniqueTag");

// If fragment doesn't exist yet, create one
if (fragment == null) {
    fTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_list, new ListFrag(), "uniqueTag");
}else { // re-use the old fragment
    fTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list, fragment, "uniqueTag");
}
```

This code is not working when add back stack.

```
fTransaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack("fragback").commit();
```

Any help?

Comment: you can use this it is helping me a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080163/android-managing-fragments-from-activity-elegantly answered by Alireza

Comment: I have same problem. When I click on back button app will close. If you got solution. Please add here for reference.